# Getting the available choices in a dropdown cell in Excel using VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vb.net, office-interop

I'm looking into getting the all possible values of a dropdown cell in Excel using VB.NET. Basically here is my code...

```
Dim excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
Dim pvw = excel.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text)
Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = pvw
Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = TryCast(wb.Sheets(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

'ws.Range("E9").Value is a dropdown cell and I want to loop through all the available values

wb.Close(True)
excel.Quit()
releaseObject(excel)
```

I just want to know what possible values there are in the dropdown so I can validate the data. How do I do this in either VB.NET or C#? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Often times the easiest way to figure out the right VB code is to open up the macro (VBA) editor in the source Excel sheet and browse the properties. Doing that, I was able to see a [`Validation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.validation) property on a range with a drop-down validation and saw the source range (in my case it was `"=$A$1:$A$3"`) on the [`Formula1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.formula1) property of that validation.  So you could get the *range* reference easily:

```
String source_ref = ws.Range("E9").Validation.Formula1
```

From there, get the range object from the formula and loop through its cells to get the values.

Comment: @D Stanley Thank you so much for your reply. I tried getting the value of source_ref and this is what comes out... =IF($A9<>"",INDIRECT(INDIRECT("Inventory!D" & MATCH(A9&C9,Inventory!A:A,0)))). I actually have no idea how to loop through this. Can you help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Also... The dropdown's values are updated in real-time based on the input of other cells. If I'm using the .NET api for excel this also triggers the updating in the dropdown values in the background right? Thank you.

Comment: Use the [`Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) method to evaluate the formula and get the range back. Then get the `Value` of the range which _should_ be an array. As to whether or not it will "auto-update" no it will not. you'll need to re-read the source after it's updated.

Comment: Hi Sir. is this what you mean? I have  Dim formulaRange As String = ws.Range("E9").Validation.Formula1. Then when I do this ws.Evaluate(formulaRange) I get a negative number. What does it mean? Sorry for asking. I get this number... -2146826265.

Comment: @Stanley Hi Sir. Can you help me please? I'm really stuck :( Thank you.

Comment: Try `Range range = ws.Evaluate(formulaRange)`

Comment: I assume it's the excel range object so, Dim range As Excel.Range = ws.Evaluate(formulaRange) but I get this error, Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range. If I open excel and input the values manually I get choices in the dropdown but when I do EVALUATE I get a negative number. Sorry for asking but I have no idea how to solve this. To explain in details, would you please be able to head over to this link? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60502050/extracting-values-from-a-dropdown-in-excel-via-vb-net-or-c-sharp Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried your code on a simple dropdown I created with 5 items with this formula... $A$1:$A$5. It actually works I'm able to get the number of rows which is 5. It doesn't work with this formula though... =IF($A9<>"",INDIRECT(INDIRECT("Inventory!D" & MATCH(A9&C9,Inventory!A:A,0)))). While the Inventory sheet is locked, I tried getting certain cell values from the Inventory sheet and I can get values, so it must not be that it's locked. I have no idea why this formula doesn't work with evaluate. I have entered into the required cells for the dropdown to produce choices. Thank you Sir.